# jsRender sum Value of Object?

Tags: jsrender

I have problem with some jsRender code

i found loop like:

```
{{for orderLines.lines}}
    <div>
        {{props >}}
          <b>{{>key}}:</b> {{>prop}}
          <br/>


        {{/props}}

    </div>
{{/for}}
```

Its Out put:

[image]

and i know i can Output value like **priceTotal**  by code:  **{{:priceTotal}}**

I need sum total price of products but i dont know how its works...

Comment: It is not `Smarty`. Maybe `Twig`?

Comment: how i can check this?

Comment: Its smartweb platform all files base on .tpl . And many code putten in smarty but here is some diferance its double {{ and : i dont know what is this and how manipulate this.

Comment: Oh its jsRender so i need read how its works

Comment: Here are some links for JsRender, showing how to output a running total, etc.

- https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@derivedfor  
- https://www.jsviews.com/#tagsapi@totals-expr  
- https://www.jsviews.com/#samples/jsr/tags/extend-for